# How to set a meta id based on previous rows in a table?

Tags: kdb

As I was writing this question, I figured out a way to do it, but it doesn't seem very "idiomatic q" to me.

Consider the following table

```
\S 123
t:`sym`time xasc ([]sym:100?10;time:100?100;price:100?10.0)
```

I want to create a meta id based on the following logic: if the sym is the same as the previous row, and the time is within 20 seconds, re-use the id from the previous row, else increment the id by 1.

Here is my solution

```
f:{[acc;elem]
    $[
        (elem[`sym] ~ acc[`prevSym]) & 20 > elem[`time] - acc[`prevTime];
        [
            acc[`prevTime]:elem[`time];
            acc
        ];
        (`id`prevTime`prevSym)!(acc[`id]+1;elem[`time];elem[`sym])
    ]
 }
update id: (exec id from ((`id`prevTime`prevSym)!(0;0;())) f\ t) from t
```

There have been many times in the past where I have asked a question about q and it turns out there is a very elegant, concise and efficient way to do it.

Is what I have the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should also achieve the same:

```
update id:sums differ[sym]|20<=deltas time from t
```

Comment: This is better than wj. Is it faster/clearer to do "update ... by sym" ?

Comment: This is that q zen I was looking for. @user20349 can you elaborate on your question? I am not sure how to fit a by clause here.

Comment: I'm not sure if the by clause would be necessary but it depends on the sorting of the data. If the data is sorted by sym as in the example, then I would think the grouping isn't necessary since it's already effectively grouped by sym and the switchover from one sym to the next is captured by the `differ[sym]`. If the data isn't grouped by sym then you definitely wouldn't want to group by sym because then that would mask the fact that sequential rows in the original table aren't the same sym

Answer (score 2):

Window join probably closest to what you want that is idiomatic.

```
q)w:-20 0+\:t.time
q)c:`sym`time
q)old:update id: (exec id from ((`id`prevTime`prevSym)!(0;0;())) f\ t) from t
q)new:update `long$sums id from wj[w;c;t;(update id:time from t;({not any -1_(last[x]-x)<20};`id))]
q)old~new
1b
```

Edit: just realised that for all the mucking about with wj you could just do an aj and it'd likely be faster. Something like:

```
q)new:update id:`long$sums (time-id)>20 from aj[`sym`time;t;update id:time from t]
```